# Why is the CountdownTimer only calling onTick once?

Tags: java, android

So I´m writing a little egg timer for learning purpose. And actually everything works fine without that the `onTick` method in the `CountDownTimer` is only calling once at the begining and I don´t get why. Actually in the documentation it´s stated that if the action called in the method takes too long ticks can be skiped but i dont think that these calculations take longer than 60 min which is the max time usable. So the timer is ticking once like if input 30 min the display widget will show 29:59.

```java
new CountDownTimer(timer,timer){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                long help = (l - (l%60000))/60000;
                String help2 = "" + help;
                Log.i("Minuten übrig", help2);
                long help3 = (l % 60000)/1000;
                String help4 = "" + help3;
                Log.i("Sekunden übrig", help4);
                String prov = help + ":" + help3;

                display.setText(prov);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                button.setText("Start");
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: You are giving the timer constructor the same value for both arguments. The timer lasts for `timer` milliseconds, and each tick is `timer` milliseconds. `timer / timer = 1`, hence one tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this :

```
new CountDownTimer(timer,timer)
```

with this:

```
new CountDownTimer(timer,1000)
```

You can put other value in place of `1000` but make sure it is less than `timer` value, else `onTick` will get called only once.

Also, check out [Chronometer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer) if your task is suited to this.